# What's the difference between Uniform Crossover (with p=0.5) and Shuffle Crossover

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

In evolutionary-/genetic algorithms there are multiple recombination methods. Most of them suffer from a bias associated with the length of the chromosome (also called positional bias).

[Uniform crossover](http://www.geatbx.com/docu/algindex-03.html#P638_39007) and [shuffle crossover](http://www.geatbx.com/docu/algindex-03.html#P647_40917) can solve this problem. However, I don't understand the difference between the two, if in case of uniform crossover `p(c)=0.5`

*Explanation*

- With uniform crossover with `p(c)=0.5` every gene is a possible
  crossover point.
- With shuffle crossover the chromosome-sequence is first shuffled
  (uniformly), then one  crossover point is assigned and finally
  the original chromosome sequence is restored - this actually means although only one crossover has taken place it could affect every position in the chromosome independently.

As both methods involve a complete randomization, I see no reason why the results should be different.

---

I wanted to know exactly therefore I wrote a little script to test both mechanisms. Here's some R-code, if you like to try it yourself

```
parent1 <- rep(0, 10000) # 10.000 genes in the chromosome - change at will
parent2 <- rep(1, length(parent1))

# Uniform crossover
offspring1_unif <- rep(-1, length(parent1)) # initialize offspring1_unif
offspring2_unif <- rep(-1, length(parent1)) # initialize offspring2_unif

for(i in 1:length(parent1)) {
  if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
    offspring1_unif[i] <- parent1[i]
    offspring2_unif[i] <- parent2[i]
  } else {
    offspring1_unif[i] <- parent2[i]
    offspring2_unif[i] <- parent1[i]
  }
}

# Shuffle crossover

## Shuffle
shuffler <- seq(1, length(parent1))
shuffler <- sample(shuffler, length(parent1))

## perform the crossover
crossover_point <- sample(1:length(parent1), 1)

offspring1_shuffle <- rep(-1, length(parent1)) # initialize offspring1_shuffle
offspring2_shuffle <- rep(-1, length(parent1)) # initialize offspring2_shuffle

for(i in 1:length(shuffler)) {
  if (i < crossover_point) {
    offspring1_shuffle[shuffler[i]] <- parent1[shuffler[i]]
    offspring2_shuffle[shuffler[i]] <- parent2[shuffler[i]]
  } else {
    offspring1_shuffle[shuffler[i]] <- parent2[shuffler[i]]
    offspring2_shuffle[shuffler[i]] <- parent1[shuffler[i]]

  }
}

mean(offspring1_unif) # 0.493
mean(offspring1_shuffle) # 0.3295

mean(offspring2_unif) # 0.507
mean(offspring2_shuffle) # 0.6705

sd(offspring1_unif) # 0.499976
sd(offspring1_shuffle) # 0.4700552

sd(offspring2_unif) # 0.499976
sd(offspring2_shuffle) # 0.4700552
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is what **distribution** the **number of swaps** has in both of the methods.

- **uniform cross-over**: 
  we pick a gene to be swapped with a probability *p independent* from the other swaps, i.e. a *Bernoulli experiment* **and** we perform this Bernoulli experiment, for the whole chromosome, i.e. let's say for *n genes*, so the number of swaps will follow a **Binomial distribution**.
- **shuffle-cross-over**: 
  we randomly shuffle the chromosome first(this is done mainly to avoid *positional bias*, i.e. to decouple the probability swaps from the position of the genes in the chromosome -- we do take care of this bias in the uniform case too. What's **different** from the uniform case, is that we pick only **one** cross-over point, and all elements on one side of this cross-over point will be swapped, so we swap any number of genes with an equal probability of 1/2. Therefore we avoid also the so called *distributional bias*, i.e. probability of number of swaps being different.

Answer (score 1):

For uniform crossover there can be many crossover points. The number of crossover points essentially becomes a binomial distribution. With `p(c)=0.5` you can expect to have around `K/2` crossover points in a `K` bit long genetic string.

Shuffle crossover on the other hand picks out one, and only one, bit at random as crossover point.

Comment: ... but concerning shuffle crossover, as far as I understand, shuffling the chromosomes before the crossover one would afterwards also expect `K/2` genes of each parent at random positions.

Comment: From the example in your question: "then **one** crossover point is assigned"